# Determine if user has set clock to 24 hours format on android device

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to determine if an android phone is set to 12 or 24 hours format. I am trying to achieve displaying time in the format set.

```
        boolean use24HourClock = ____________________
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat;
        if (use24HourClock) {
            timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm ", Locale.ENGLISH);
        } else {
            timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
        }

I did not find a way to determine from the settings. Any suggestions?
```

Comment: [TimeManager class](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/things/device/TimeManager)

Comment: Note that [the methods on `DateUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils) will take this user setting into account.

Comment: +1. Event though I do not use java for coding android apps, I still think questions about how to do simple things like this are important

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)
```

from `android.text.format` to determine is system 24hours or 12.